# Vertical highlight (column selection) in Xcode

Tags: xcode, text-editor, highlighting

How do you highlight a rectangular selection in Xcode?

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Hold down the Option key while clicking and dragging**.

Normal copy and paste rules (command-c and command-v) apply when doing a vertical highlight / block select.

Comment: I can copy it, but when I paste it, it doesn't paste it in "block" mode.  It pastes the text normally and reaaligns all of the succeeding lines.  Have you found a way to paste the text vertically too?

Comment: AFAIK as I know you can't paste into a vertical block. If you figure out how though, please share.

Comment: @KyleClegg, It certainly used to be possible. Pasting a selection would intelligently paste each line on subsequent line at the same column. I'm sure there are still some applications I use that do it but I can't remember which!

Comment: It was also possible to e.g. select a single word, then rectangular-select a column. Pasting would then paste multiple instances of the selected word.

Answer (score 0):

Place cursor on the upper left corner of the block you want to select.
Press OPTION Button and keep pressed, press touch pad, keep pressed while moving the cursor to desired lower right corner.
Voila. You have slected a block that you can copy, delete, replace.
You can also insert charcters as a column if moving cursor only down and to to the right.
Using XCode Version 13.4 (13F17a) on MacOS 12.1 on Mac M1.