# Column Select Xcode

Tags: xcode, select, multiple-columns

I'm wondering how to paste on multiple lines in XCode?

I enter column select mode by pressing option and dragging.  But once I apple + V the text I wish to paste over multiple lines, it only pastes on the first line, and not the multiple lines selected when in column select mode.

Does XCode have this feature?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do. I column select just before CGPointFromString and want to paste in [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:

I'm doing it manually at the moment but it's a real pain.

```
[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{17.5,73.5}")],
           [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{121.5,81.5}")],
           [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{121.5, 81.5}")],
           [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{247.5, 88}")],
           [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{294, 87.5}")],
          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{23.5, 94.5}"),
          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{23, 96}"),
          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{27.5, 95}"),
          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{27, 97.5}"),
          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{21, 104}"),
          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{25.5, 95}"),
          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{27, 99}"),
          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{31.5, 94}"),
          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{29, 94.5}"),
          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{28, 99.5}"),
          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{23.5, 102.5}"),
          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{25, 96.5}"),
          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{24.5, 93.5}"),
          [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointFromString(@"{29, 99.5}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{24.5, 99.5}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{27, 98.5}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{25.5, 102.5}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{31.5, 98.5}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{25, 96.5}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{28, 95}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{111.5, 138}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{184, 148}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{238.5, 144.5}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{117, 213.5}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{161, 216}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{201.5, 217.5}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{80, 143}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{155, 145.5}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{229.5, 146.5}"),
          CGPointFromString(@"{297, 151}"),
```

Comment: As far as I can tell there isn't. I've made due by copy-pasting the code into another editor (in my case, Notepad++ on Parallels) and using column mode there, then copy/pasting that back into Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro the issue here - an example of the text that is causing this problem would be useful.

However, some issues like this can be solved by using Paste and Preserve Formatting (command-shift-option-V). Try that.

Comment: Actually just found the same question asked elsewhere and the answerer thinks it's not possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892816/vertical-highlight-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else dropping in on late this thread like I did, paste in column mode works exactly as one would anticipate in XCode 11 Beta. I don't know when this feature would have been fixed - it could be working for earlier versions too, since the OP was 4 years ago. Works brilliantly (thank you @Linda Keating)!